# HTML encoding in chrome/firefox

Tags: html, dom, character-encoding

I have a textBox whose value is getting displayed in different Manner in IE and chrome.

For example :

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="&#0;"/>
```

Output in IE8  : `<input id="myInput" type="text" value="&#0;">`

Output in Chrome : `<input id="myInput" type="text" value="�">`

How to achieve the same behavior like IE8 in chrome? I do not want to set the value separately
using javascript or jquery. This value has to be there in html file while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You must set meta in head

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>
```

And set same encoding of this file

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 (and IE 9) is in error when it comes to processing `&#0;`. This reference means the NULL character, which is invalid in HTML. HTML5 [specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state) that the error be processed so that NULL is replaced by U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER “�”.

There is no way to achieve the old erroneous handling in modern browsers.

If you actually wanted to set the default (initial) value of the `input` element to the literal string `&#0;` (four Ascii characters), use `value="&amp;#0;"`, i.e. the normal `&amp;` escape for `&`.